# Spliting paragraphs that endswith "." and new line after dot in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, pdfbox

I am trying to read text from PDF file and split each paragraph and put it into ArrayList and print elements of ArrayList but I have no outputs

```
String path = "E:\\test.pdf";
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
PDDocument pdDoc = null;
COSDocument cosDoc = null;
File file = new File(path);

PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
parser.parse();
cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);

pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
pdfStripper.setEndPage(1);

String page = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
String[] paragraph = page.split("\n");
ArrayList<String> ramy = new ArrayList<>();
String p = "";
for (String x : paragraph) {

    if ((x.endsWith("\\.")) || (x.endsWith("\\." + "\\s+"))) {
        p += x;
        ramy.add(p);
        p = "";
    } else {
        p += x;
    }

}

for (String x : ramy) {
    System.out.print(x + "\n\n");
}
```

Note : I am using NetBeans 8.0.2, windows 8.1 and pdfbox library to read from pdf file.

Comment: `endsWith` doesn't use regex so probably there is no need for `\\.` or `\\s`.

Comment: BTW, don't use concatenation to add new strings to already existing one `p += x;` because each time you execute this code it needs to copy original string and new string to create new string instance holding `original+new` parts. Instead use `StringBuilder` and its `append` method. When you are done simply use `toString` on this builder.

Comment: can i split paragraphs using breakiterator ?
and if yes how can do that

Comment: It looks like I misread your question. Judging by "ends with dot" I assumed you ware asking about sentences, not paragraphs. Will reopen your question. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: BTW I am not sure if `BreakIterator.getLineInstance` can be used to find paragraphs but you can try with that.

Answer (score 0):

The most crippling bug you have is that you are calling `endsWith()` with `"\\."`, which is two characters; a literal backslash and a literal dot (*not* an escaped dot) and again with `"\\.\\s+"` (again all literal characters). It's clear you (incorrectly) believed that the method accepts regex, which it doesn't.

Assuming your logic is sound, change your test to use a regex-based test:

```
 if (x.matches(".*\\.\\s*"))
```

This test combines the intention of your code into one test.

Note that you don't need to end the regex with `$`, because `matches()` must match the *whole* string to return `true`, so `^` and `$` are *implied* at the start/end of the pattern.